# GitHub Private Repository has maven dependency

Tags: maven, selenium, github, automation, artifact

Hi can anyone explain me on how to get private GitHub repositories as my maven dependencies???

I was able to get only public GitHub repositories as my maven dependencies.

Comment: How do you get public github repositories as your maven dependencies?

Comment: Hi Thorbjorn,

I have got the public repo by adding the below repository in to my POM.

<repositories>
    <repository>
 <id>USER NAME</id>
      <name>REPO NAME</name>
      <url>Repo Url</url>
    </repository>
   </repositories>

I have followed the below two links and proceeded:

https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/06/how-to-host-a-maven-artifact-on-github/


https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/06/how-to-use-github-hosted-maven-artifact-in-a-maven-project/

Comment: Sounds like github does not like the maven authentification scheme.  Then you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Oh God! Will that be possible by OSSRH process.

http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html

Comment: That is only for open source projects, which yo normally do not keep in private repositories.  Perhaps you should elaborate on what problem you need solved instead.

Comment: Are you inside a company? If so you should start using a repository manager which should solve the problem with private git repositories...

Comment: Hi Thorbjorn,

Please find the detailed issue from the link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585927/using-java-project-as-jar-file-in-other-project-as-maven-dependency

Comment: Hi Khmarbaise,

Can you please elaborate on Repository Manager???